# matplotlib plotting dictionary keys as column labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm tripping over my feet here with this very simple task.

I want to plot as a bar chart in matplotlib, where the keys are the labels of the columns, and the height of each bar is the value.

e.g.

```
data = {
    'Alex': 20,
    'Jason': 35
}
```

And I want to get

```
|    
|    *
|    *
|    *
| *  *
| *  *
| *  *
| *  *  
| --------------------
| A  J
| l  a
| e  s
| x  o
|    n
```

etc.  I know this should be very simple but I can't seem to think straight... anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why down-voted? The question may be a simple one, but there's nothing wrong with that...

Comment: Downvotes are due to the lack of research effort (if you look at the reasons for downvotes, it says "This question does not show any research effort"). I mean , you can go to matplotlib's page and then 'gallery' and find what you need in under a minute. This is a classic reason to be downvoted and happens to everyone, nothing to worry about unless you value your reputation higher than the knowledge you get :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bar plot, see an [example on matplotlib page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html).

Slightly modified version for your case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'Alex': 20, 'Jason': 35}
x = np.arange(len(data))
y = data.values()

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(x + 0.5, data.keys(), rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```